# Give first 5 terms of series for differential equation y' = y^2, y(0) = 1

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

This is problem #33, section 8.6 Power Series from textbook APEX Calculus v4. The problem asks to give the first five terms that is the solution to the given differential equation:
$$
y' = y^2, y(0) = 1
$$
The book answer is $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4$.

I know that the a power series centered at 0 is defined as $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nx^n$.
I know the derivative of that power series is $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n \cdot n \cdot x^{n-1}$. I could not easily define the terms of the series where
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n \cdot n \cdot x^{n-1} = (\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_nx^n)^2.
$$
So I took the second derivative of y which is $y'' =\sum^{\infty}_{n=2} a_n \cdot n(n-1) \cdot x^{n-2}$. Reindexing to zero the second derivative gives me $y'' = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n+2} \cdot (n+1)(n+2) \cdot x^n$. I know that $y' = y^2$ and $y'' = 2yy'$.

This is not part of a class hence I don't have an instructor to ask. I'm just going through the book on my own and I don't have a strong understanding of differential equations. Can someone help me figure out what to do?

Edit: I realized that $y'' = 2yy'$ as others here have said and that introduced an error in my problem solving. However, I still would have been stuck on how to proceed further from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the equation instead...
\begin{align*}
y' = & y^2 \rightarrow y'(0) = 1^2 = 1 \\
y'' =& (y^2)' = 2 y' y = 2y^3 \Rightarrow y''(0)=2 \\
y''' = & (2 y^3)' = 6 y' y^2 = 6 y^4 \Rightarrow  y'''(0) = 6\\
\vdots
\end{align*}

This way you see that
$$
y(x)=y(0) + y'(0) x + \frac 12 y''(0) x^2 + \frac 16 y'''(0)x^3+ \cdots = 1+x+x^2+x^3+ \cdots
$$

**note 1:** I'm assuming that the differential equation is satisfied at $x=0$, whicj is not always the case.

**note 2:** If the Taylor/MacLaurin theorem is not to be used, just derive the series...

\begin{align*} 
y(x)= &a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots \\
y'(x)= &a_1 +  2 a_2 x + 3 a_3 x^2 + \cdots \Rightarrow y'(0) = a_1 \Rightarrow a_1=y'(0)\\
y''(x)= &2 a_2 + 6 a_3 x + \cdots \Rightarrow y''(0) = 2 a_2 \Rightarrow a_2 = \frac 12 y''(0)\\
\vdots
\end{align*}

Comment: This was the solution that made the most sense to me. It looks like you're defining the function as a Maclauren polynomial which unfortunately is not covered until the next section in the textbook. Hence, I was unaware of this method based on the progress I had made thus far in the book.

Comment: @swac When you derive the series term by term, you immediately identify the coefficients in the series with the derivatives of $y$ at $x=0$. It is just a matter of computing $a_n$ by deriving the series and evaluating at $x=0$ each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can still proceed with your method, at least up to the point where you differentiate both sides, and there's no need to extract a recurrence for all the coefficients $a_n$.

Assume a solution of the form

$$y=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+\cdots$$

so that the initial conditions tells us $y(0)=1\implies a_0=1$.

Write the ODE in terms of power series:

$$\begin{align}
y'&=y^2\\[1ex]
\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n&=\left(\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n\right)^2\\[1ex]
\underbrace{\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n+1}(n+1)x^n}_A&=\underbrace{\sum_{n\ge0}(a_nx^n)^2}_B+2\underbrace{\sum_{0\le i<j\\i+j\ge1}a_ia_jx^{i+j}}_C
\end{align}$$

You want the first $5$ terms in the series, so we need only consider up to $n=4$ (you'll see why only $4$ momentarily):

$$A=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3+5a_5x^4+\cdots$$

$$B+C={a_0}^2+2a_0a_1x+({a_1}^2+2a_0a_2)x^2+(2a_0a_3+2a_1a_2)x^3+({a_2}^2+2a_0a_4+2a_1a_3)x^4+\cdots$$

Matching up and solving for the coefficients gives

$$\begin{cases}a_0=1&\text{given}\\
a_1={a_0}^2&x^0\\
2a_2=2a_0a_1&x^1\\
3a_3={a_1}^2+2a_0a_2&x^2\\
4a_4=2a_0a_3+2a_1a_2&x^3\\
5a_5={a_2}^2+2a_0a_4+2a_1a_3&x^4
\end{cases}\implies \{a_n\}_{n=0}^{n=4}=\left\{1,1,1,1,1\right\}$$

so the series solution is indeed $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $y''=2y$ is wrong. It should be $y''=2yy'$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find this is to solve the differential equation and then work out it's series expansion.

The ODE is easily solved as :

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=y^2$$

Gives :

$$\frac d {dx} \left( \frac 1 y \right) = -1$$

and this, with condition $y(0)=1$ gives a solution :

$$y(x)=\frac 1 {1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+\dots$$

Comment: This works as well, but is not really the point of the exercise.

Comment: @K.defaoite The OP specifically mentioned they lacked an understanding of differential equations and this seems precisely to the point to me.  I think a lot of people are focusing on the power series issue, but it is better (IMO) to show people to look for the simplest approach to solve a mathematics problem, not just do grind for grind's sake.  Remember, the OP is self studying - they lack a tutor to explore options.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps OP needs to revisit earlier chapters.

Comment: The earlier chapters in the book do not cover differential equations. It's primarily focused on limits, derivatives, integration, sequences, and series. Later chapters in the book mostly cover multivariable calculus. I recognize that you basically solved for a geometric series and for a convergent geometric series, ( $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} r^n, |r| < 1$) it is equal to $\frac{1}{1-r}$. I probably need to do more studying separately in solving ODEs with a different textbook.

Comment: @swac Really practice with integration and differentiation covers most of the useful tricks (with calculus) starting out.  I would not worry about ODEs until you need to and a separate book is probably overkill.